# How do I pass an array of chars to a function?

Tags: c

This is my code :

```
void render(char * world) {...} 
int main() { 
  char world[HEIGHT * WIDTH]; 
  render(&world); 
  return 0; 
 }
```

Tell me if I have given enough information! 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `world` is already a pointer, `&world` becomes a pointer to a pointer... that's not what you want. Remove the `&`.

Comment: No, `world` is not a pointer.  It is an array.  When passed as an argument to `render`, the address is passed (the argument decays to a pointer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass `world`. Passing `&world` is passing the address of `world`, which is already a `char *`, so you're passing a `char **`.

Comment: @ahota, this is not accurate.  `char world[x]` and `char *world` declare two different types of variables.  An array is not a pointer.  It is not merely syntactic sugar.

Comment: @WilliamPursell you're right, my mistake. The array decays to a pointer, but isn't the same as one.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it with:

```
 void render(char * world) {...} 
 int main() { 
  char world[HEIGHT * WIDTH]; 
  render(world); 
  return 0; 
 }
```